# Stimulsoft Report - Hide Component Bands in Designer

Tags: stimulsoft

Is there a way we could hide Report Title Band or any other Band in Stimulsoft Report Designer ?

StiOptions.Designer.ComponentsTypes.Bands.ReportTitleBand.IsVisible seems to be readonly property, is there anything else we can use ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, thought of sharing it here so that it could be useful any one else who has same question.

You need to do the following before the InitializeComponent.

```
foreach (var component in StiOptions.Services.Components)
        {

            if (component.ComponentId == StiComponentId.StiReportTitleBand)
                component.ServiceEnabled = false;
        }
```